# Barra de carga no imprime lo que le pido

Tags: c

Quiero agregar una función que haga una ilusion de carga,
es decir que aparezca "Cargando" y sucesivamente aparezcan 5 puntos, pero con el código que tengo esos puntos los cambia por íconos distintos. Tengo idea de que es por el código ascii pero no sé cómo corregirlo.

```
//funcion de cargando
void carga(){
    int contador, vueltas = 0;
    char puntos[5] = (".....");
    do{
    printf("\nCargando");
    for (contador = 0; contador < 5; contador++)
    {
        printf("%c", puntos);
        Sleep(500);
    }
        vueltas = vueltas + 1;
    system("cls");
    }while(vueltas <= 5);
}
```

[image: Imagen de salida en consola]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mi me funciona así:

```
void carga(){
    int contador, vueltas = 0;
   
    do{
    printf("\nCargando");
    for (contador = 0; contador < 5; contador++)
    {
        putchar('.');
        _sleep(500);
    }
        vueltas = vueltas + 1;
    system("cls");
    }while(vueltas <= 5);
}
```

En tu caso también podrías reemplazar la línea donde sacas el punto por:

```
printf("%c", puntos[contador]);
```

**Se estaba cogiendo un punteros a caracteres como un carácter(mala cosa)**

Comment: muchas gracias, no tenia idea que existia putchar, y una pregunta ¿Cual es la diferencia entre _sleep y Sleep?

Comment: Hacen lo mismo, _sleep esta definida en Time.h que es mas estándar.